# JMeter and end-to-end testing

Tags: scripting, jmeter, jmx

I have a jmx script that is being used to perform functional and load testing.

The script tests, using 1 user and multiple thread users, a simple order management system that does the following for things:

1. Load the System
2. Login
3. Order Placement (select a product, add to cart, check out, submit order till Order Confirmation Page)
4. Logout

These steps become steps in the  jmx script.

When the script is executed, I see no major issues. JMeter does not report any errors as its gathering performance metrics and processing times.

However post-testing, when we check the database (and the System itself outside of JMeter) - those orders, that should have been created when we ran the JMeter test are not being created.

I assume that when JMeter logs in as a dummy user and performs any transactions on the UI, those transactions see their way through to the database. There is a transaction that goes end-to-end. But it appears that this is not the case here.

Any ideas so as to what might be causing this?
Does JMeter actually push out the actions on the UI all the way to the back-end?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find answer to your question ? Please gve feedback ...

Answer (score 3):

First, JMeter is not a browser, it reproduces only trafic with server.

Second, are you adding assertions to check that responses are ok and contain what they should?

Third, you say you use 1 user and N threads, of by this you mean you only have 1 user That you multithread then you test is wrong as it Will provoke caching, transaction contention...

I suggest you Check your script first with one user and view results tree listener. Then check your users by running them all with low number of threads.

Finally run real load test.